# Cannot assign "abc@gmail.com". "Invitation.friend" must be a "Invitation" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am developing a referral program. It is referring a friend to join our community. I have a model called Invitation. I have used two form with same model. In the first form, the user has to fill the form with just his/her email address. When he request for invitation, he/she can now refer to his/her friends. The point will be gained if the referred friend clicks the referred link that is sent by him.

My first form, i.e request for invitation is working but when after requesting for invitation, if he/she tries to refer to the friend filling his email adress and his/her friend's email address, i get an error of

> Cannot assign "abc@gmail.com". "Invitation.friend" must be a
>   "Invitation" instance.

How can i save the refered email adress(friend) to database?

Here is my models.py

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name=_("e-mail Address"))
    friend = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name="referral", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invite_code = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    invite_accepted = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('invite accepted'), default=False)
    request_approved = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('request accepted'))
```

**forms.py**

```
class ReferForm(forms.Form):
    sender_email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Your email"), required=True)
    receiver_email = forms.EmailField(label=_("To email"), required=True)

    def save(self, sender_email, receiver_email):
        print('email', sender_email, receiver_email)
        new_join, created = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=sender_email)
        print ('new_join is', new_join, created)
        if created:
            return True
        return new_join
```

**views.py**

```
class ReferInvitation(FormView):
    template_name = 'refer/refer.html'
    form_class = ReferForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        sender_email = form.cleaned_data.get('sender_email')
        receiver_email = form.cleaned_data.get('receiver_email')
        print ('sender_email', sender_email)
        print ('friend', receiver_email)
        refer_instance = form.save(sender_email, receiver_email)
        print ('refer_instance', refer_instance)
        refer_instance.friend = receiver_email
        refer_instance.invite_code = get_invite_code()
        refer_instance.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'You invited {0} successfully'.format(receiver_email))
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

One doubt: The sender email is already saved to database when he requested for invitation. Is my way effective?

**UPDATE**

Like i have said, Invitation model is used by two form. First the RequestInvitation form uses it so a user can request for invitation and only that user can use refer form. So when submitting form, if i do `Invitation.objects.create(email=sender_email, friend=reciever_email)` i get

> unique_constraint error on invitation_invitation.email

. To handle that i tried to do

```
def save(self, sender_email, receiver_email):
    try:
        invite_instance = Invitation.objects.get(email=sender_email)
    except:
        invite_instance = None
    if invite_instance:
        invite_instance.friend = receiver_email
        return invite_instance
    return Invitation.objects.create(email=sender_email, friend=receiver_email)
```

This way if i directly go to refer form and fill the sender_email and reciever_email then it works. If i go to refer form after requesting for invitation and fill the refer form, then the friend field is empty.

Comment: change  ` refer_instance.friend = receiver_email` to `        refer_instance.instance.friend = receiver_email`

Comment: @BernardParah i get 'Invitation' object has no attribute 'instance' error.

Comment: I think i have problem with the save function too.

Comment: yea, are you open to an alternative way of doing this with less code using the CreateView CBV?

Comment: Yes i am but i want to know why is this error happening? Can you explain me that too?

Answer (score 0):

When submitting the form, don't save it to the db yet, set it to false hence saying you have more things you want to do with it.

Here is a  working solution with the main change being the FK used on the model.

Model.

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name=("e-mail Address"))
    friend = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True) # this was just because I didn't have any model to tie the FK to'
```

Form

```
from django import forms
from .models import Invitation


class ReferForm(forms.Form):
    sender_email = forms.EmailField(label=("Your email"), required=True)
    receiver_email = forms.EmailField(label=("To email"), required=True)

def save(self, sender_email, receiver_email):
    print('email', sender_email, receiver_email)
    #add the friend=receiver_email param as part of the argument for saving the form
    new_join, created = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=sender_email, friend=receiver_email)
    print ('new_join is', new_join, created)
    if created:
        return True
    return new_join
```

View

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

from .forms import ReferForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .models import Invitation

```
class ReferInvitation(FormView):
    template_name = 'refer.html'
    form_class = ReferForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        sender_email = form.cleaned_data.get('sender_email')
        receiver_email = form.cleaned_data.get('receiver_email')
        print ('refer_instance', refer_instance)
        #saving  and updating in the same view is not allowed in django which is why you were getting the first error
        # moved the saving of the form to the db down, you can do every other thing before saving
        form.save(sender_email, receiver_email)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: I am not using modelForm so i think i am getting save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'.

Comment: sorry  I missed that you're not subclassing a ModelForm...updating my answer

Comment: I tried instantiating Invitation object and save to database but is not working either

Comment: your uses a ForeignKey, to what exactly? I have a working solution but without the foreignkey

Comment: Like i have said in question that Invitation model is used by two form. One Request for Invitation and another this refer form. The email field is already saved when user is requesting for invitation. So if i again do Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=sender_email, friend=receiver_email) i get unique_constraint error on invitation_invitation.email.

Comment: I tried to handle that in my forms.py with def save(self, sender_email, receiver_email):
        invite_instance = Invitation.objects.get(email=sender_email)
        if invite_instance:
            print ('inv')
            invite_instance.friend = receiver_email
            print ('invite_instance', invite_instance.friend)
            return invite_instance
        return Invitation.objects.create(email=sender_email, friend=receiver_email) but friend field is not saved in database. It is still empty

Comment: Do you think a user can invite many other user if not used FK?